# Asycio/hypercorn/SSL error, all unhandled, in a Quart based restapi

Tags: ssl, http, python

I'm writing a restapi in quart, served by Hypercorn, using a TLS certificate made by [BenMorel's scripts](https://github.com/BenMorel/dev-certificates). My single python file's structure is something like this:

```
import asyncio
from quart import Quart, request, abort, make_response, Response
from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

(...)
app = Quart(__name__)
(...)

@app.route(URL_BASE_PATH + "/get-stats", methods=['GET'])
async def getStats():
    (...)
    return {
        "query-able-first-date":firstDate,
        "query-able-last-date":lastDate,
        "free-space":freeSpace,
    }

(...)
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
        config = Config()
        config.bind = ["0.0.0.0:" + str(SERVER_PORT)]

        if TLS_ENABLED:
            if os.path.isfile(TLS_CERT) and os.path.isfile(TLS_PRIVKEY):
                config.certfile = TLS_CERT
                config.keyfile = TLS_PRIVKEY
            else:
                print("TLS private key or certificate is missing, cannot use TLS")

        asyncio.run(serve(app, config))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Some error message")
        sys.exit(1)
```

This is all great, if I'm not using TLS. However, if I do, and lookup this page in browser (in Firefox or Chrome), I get a "few" unhandled errors:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-6' coro=<worker_serve.<locals>._server_callback() done, defined at /home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/run.py:94> exception=SSLError(1, '[SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2745)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 70, in run
    await self._read_data()
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 106, in _read_data
    await self.protocol.handle(RawData(data))
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/__init__.py", line 62, in handle
    return await self.protocol.handle(event)
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/h2.py", line 188, in handle
    await self._handle_events(events)
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/h2.py", line 255, in _handle_events
    await self.streams[event.stream_id].handle(EndBody(stream_id=event.stream_id))
KeyError: 15

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 70, in run
    await self._read_data()
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/task_group.py", line 82, in __aexit__
    await task
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/task_group.py", line 78, in __aexit__
    await task
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/run.py", line 96, in _server_callback
    await TCPServer(app, loop, config, context, reader, writer)
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 74, in run
    await self._close()
  File "/home/sga/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/asyncio/tcp_server.py", line 118, in _close
    await self.writer.wait_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/streams.py", line 359, in wait_closed
    await self._protocol._get_close_waiter(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 528, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 206, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.unwrap()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 948, in unwrap
    return self._sslobj.shutdown()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: APPLICATION_DATA_AFTER_CLOSE_NOTIFY] application data after close notify (_ssl.c:2745)
```

Since all I'm doing is calling hypercorn.serve inside asyncio, I can't do much about the unhandled errors... In Firefox, I imported my fake, self-signed cert and got Keyerror: 15, in chrome where I didn't (just accepted the very harmful consequences) I got Keyerror: 1. Besides that, the same errors occur with both browsers, as clients.

I get that this SSL error means the server got data AFTER closing the SSL connection, though I don't have any idea why this happens. I also see that the asyncio fails and thus gives a "CancelledError" message...though the application and thus the restapi server keeps on running, and I even got my results in the browser. What I don't get is how to solve this issue, or where to start at debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this problem only occurs with web browsers. With an up-to-date curl (which does support HTTP/2) if I ask the page (`curl -kv --http https://IP:port/resource`), it's working just fine...